# Is "double exclamation" same as "as" in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Assume that we have variable like `var text: String?`.

When I want to cast it to non nullable type I can use:

- `text!!`
- `text as String`

Does they mean the same?

I know that these ways will throw an exception if `text` is `null`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are basically the same thing.

In Kotlin 1.3 (or older) first one will throw  `KotlinNullPointerExcption` for `null`, and second one will  throw `TypeCastException`.

Kotlin 1.4 stops using its own exceptions and both expressions fail with regular NPE but `as` version has a detailed message:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String`

Comment: Exactly what is expected.

Comment: Note: starting from Kotlin 1.4, a `java.lang.NullPointerException` will be thrown instead of `KotlinNullPointerException` ([source](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/08/kotlin-1-3-50-released/)). In Kotlin/JVM, the former exists [as a typealias `kotlin.NullPointerException`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-null-pointer-exception/index.html), so you don't need to explicitly import/qualify the `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the exception (either `KotlinNullPointerExcption` or `TypeCastException`) you get when `text == null` (as @Miha_x64 has stated) in every other regard they generate the same bytecode. Also the cast and the !! are only valid in the current statement, so the behaviour is unlikely to change. I would go for `!!` every time, because the exception reflects the error better.

```
fun foo() {
    var s = ""
    val t: String? = ""

    if (t as String != "") s = "1"
    if (t!! != "") s = "2"
}
```

yields

```
public final foo()V
L0
  LINENUMBER 9 L0
  LDC ""
  ASTORE 1
L1
  LINENUMBER 10 L1
  LDC ""
  ASTORE 2
L2
  LINENUMBER 12 L2
  ALOAD 2
L3
  LDC ""
  INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.areEqual (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  ICONST_1
  IXOR
  IFEQ L4
  LDC "1"
  ASTORE 1
L4
  LINENUMBER 13 L4
  ALOAD 2
L5
LDC ""
  INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.areEqual (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
  ICONST_1
  IXOR
  IFEQ L6
  LDC "2"
  ASTORE 1
L6
  LINENUMBER 14 L6
  RETURN
L7
  LOCALVARIABLE t Ljava/lang/String; L2 L7 2
  LOCALVARIABLE s Ljava/lang/String; L1 L7 1
  LOCALVARIABLE this Lde/leo; L0 L7 0
  MAXSTACK = 2
  MAXLOCALS = 3
```

The interesting part is **L3** and **L5**

Comment: The behavior is likely to change in the sense that if `String?` is changed to something else (and we don't know how likely it is), `as String` means two places have to be changed, and `!!` only one.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov do you mean if the program changes or that Kotlin will change?

Comment: If the program changes.

Answer (score 2):

It's different in the resulting exception:

The cast of a nullable value to its non-null type causes a `TypeCastException` if `null`:

```
val s: String? = null
val s2 = s as String //kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String
```

The double exclamation mark, double bang, means that you don't care of a type's nullability information and just want to use it as if it can't be `null`. In case it is, a `NullpointerException` is thrown:

```
val s: String? = null
val s2: String = s!! //Exception in thread "main" kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
```

You should rarely use either of the two options and handle nullability cautiously instead:

```
s?.let {
    //it's safe here!
} ?: //optionally handle null case
```

[Smart casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#smart-casts) will help you, too.

Answer (score 1):

They are the same in the sense that they will throw an exception error if used incorrectly. According to the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html) when using the `as` operator you're performing an unsafe operation and if they are not of the same type it will throw an error, whereas the [force unwrap](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) `!!` will throw an error only if the variable being unwraped is null.