# How to safely cast the result of readLine() to prevent a Type Mismatch using Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, type-mismatch

Many Kotlin tutorials I have watched / read have this line of code:

```
var number = Integer.valueOf(readLine())
```

And while it clearly worked before, it is now throwing a compiler error while using Android studio and Kotlin version `1.3.50`. 
It indicates a type mismatch where the found is `String?` and the required is `String`.

Granted, I understand *why* this is happening, I get that a user could pass null or empty values in via the console and therefore it needs to have the optional null declaration, but I would like to understand how to fix the compiler error and keep similar code without changing too much.

While I can use both of these lines of code:

```
var number = Integer.valueOf(readLine()!!)
```

and

```
var number = Integer.valueOf(readLine() as String)
```

I believe those can throw different exceptions as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48775773/2480714)

I know I am able to 'fix' this problem by using this code:

```
var number : String? = readLine();
if(number == null){
    number = "0"
}
val number2 = Integer.valueOf(number);
```

But it seems horribly inefficient. Is there a shorter way to do this using native Kotlin code?

Comment: Use the Elvis operator to specify a default for when the result is null. `readLine()?: “0”`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we simply call `toInt()` on the result from `readLine()`, we will get an exception if the value provided isn't an actual Integer. In order to avoid an exception, we can use `toIntOrNull()` from the Kotlin Standard Library.

```
val x= readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: 0
```

In this case, we read the line (as a `String?`) and if it is non-null, call `toIntOrNull()` on it. If *that* is non-null, we have our answer. Otherwise, we use `0` as the default.

Answer (score 2):

Even though I am primarily a Swift developer, this is a very similar concept. In Swift it is called a nil-coalescing operator, but apparently in Kotlin it is called the Elvis Operator (uh-huh).

The docs are [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)  So your code would look like this:

`var num : String = readLine() ?: "0";`

If the value before the Elvis operator `?:` is not null, it uses that, otherwise it uses the second default value you provide.

Comment: This answer is valid and makes it so I can utilize the `existing` sample code I mentioned, so +1 for that, but I will mark the other answer as correct just since it also shortens the needed code, too. 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can also put:

```
var str = readLine().toString();
```

it works to me!